# Python - How to display data from a streaming source

Tags: python

I'm new to Python (and computer programming) but for my employer I have set up a Python script updates 30 different variables as new data comes in from a streaming source.

What is the best or easiest way to display these 30 variables in a table that updates as the variables change?

Currently I have the script printing a new table to the console every time one of the variables changes and it leaves me with a giant collections of tables and I assume there is a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a terminal display, you could try the built in [curses library](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) for an updating, not constantly pinning table of data.

Comment: Thanks. What other options do I have other than a terminal display?

Comment: You could go the GUI route with something like tkinter: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html

Comment: Or Bokeh for a Web-based dashboard.

Comment: These are all new to me so I'll have to look into each option individually. Which would be the easiest to learn and implement between the curses, GUI and Bokeh web app?

Comment: Curses would probably be the lowest friction change. Tkinter is event driven programming, so a bit of a change in thinking if you haven't done gui programming. Not sure about bokeh.